# How do you change the result of Encoding.Default?

Tags: .net, string, c#-4.0, character-encoding

We have a third party library which handles a special file and, in the process, calculates its checksum. Sometimes in our runtime environment the checksum check fails. Through JustDecompile I can see that the code is using [Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I want to create test code that demonstrates this behaviour. Can I change the result of Encoding.Default? Can I change the current codepage?

Comment: I would be very wary of such a library - if they're making such a basic mistake, do you really trust the rest of their code? Are you able to log a bug with them? I think it should be pretty obvious to the authors what the problem is if you just point it out - I don't think you should need to create a test in this particular case. (I applaud the general attitude, mind you.)

Comment: I agree. Yes, we can log a bug with them. It's a library they've written for another department in our company. Due to internal politics, a good demonstration of the problem will go a long way.

Comment: Wow, if it's within the same company why did you need to use JustDecompile at all? This internal politics sounds crazy...

Comment: "Sunk cost fallacy", ftw. The warning in the MSDN docs will probably do the trick. I assume that if you knew how to go about manipulating Encoding.Default, I would have your code running on my machine by now.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. I got as far as looking for a native call to do it, but didn't find one.

Comment: The point is to not use Encoding.Default but the encoding that's the default where-ever that file was generated.  Like Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) in your neck of the woods, 1250 if it came from Eastern Europe, etc.  And no, don't bother, ask for a change to utf-8.